# Laravel route directing to Home instead of throwing a NotFoundHttpException

Tags: php, apache, laravel, routes

I'm experiencing some unexpected behaviour in my laravel (4.2) routes.

Let's say my server is available at https://example.com. If I enter https://example.com/whatever/index.php I would expect laravel to throw a  NotFoundHttpException, because a route to "whatever" is not defined. Instead laravel shows me the start page, indicating that my "home" route was catched.

If I solely enter https://example.com/whatever everything is fine (i.e. I get the NotFoundHttpException as expected). I neither have the problem on my localhost. Here https://localhost/laravel/whatever/index.php throws the NotFoundHttpException as expected.

My routes.php file:

```
// Home
Route::get('/', array( 'as' => 'home', function() {
    return View::make('home');
}));
```

Maybe someone can give me a hint where to start searching what's causing that behaviour: Apache config, PHP config, Laravel config?

Ammendment as answer to S. Safdar:
At first I thought of a .htaccess redirect issue, too. In laravel's public folder (the web servers root dir) lays a .htaccess as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

As you can see, the redirect here is handled correctly. The requested "whatever/index.php" is no real file therefore it is redirected to be handled by laravels index.php. If I remove the Rewrite Conditions (plus Rule) I get a regular apache 404 error page. In my case that's of no help as I want laravel to correctly(!) handle all error pages. But for some reason laravels home route matches every url ending on /index.php.

Comment: what error you have?

Comment: Well, if i'm not getting your question wrongly, than your redirection might be from apache  side, but still not sure. Reason behind is the all url's crossing Laravel Front Controller file they will throw 404 by Laravel and in all others cases apache 404 error will occur. Try to rewrite 404 page redirection through htaccess, and let me if its really apache redirection or not.

Comment: @Deena: I'm getting no error, that's the point. It should throw a NotFoundHttpException but instead it routes to my HomeController as if "whatever/index.php" would have been set as proper route.

Comment: did you have home.php in view?

Comment: @Deena: yes, I have a home.blade.php. For testing purposes its the standard welcome screen of laravel

Comment: your code is working for me

Comment: add dummy file in view with test data and try it

Comment: post your home.blade.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this issue is present with both nginx and apache servers.  A few steps I took to mitigate the issue with **apache**:

#### Change the index.php filename:

```
public/index.php to public/start.php
```

#### Change .htaccess to read:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ start.php [L]
```

#### Change the reference to index.php in the server.php file to have:

```
require_once $paths['public'].'/start.php';
```

Comment: Well, actually I don't use Laravel any more and switched to Symfony 2. So I can't test your answer for know. As changing the index.php filename sounds pretty logical for me, I'll accept your answer, but I'm still wondering what causes this issue in the end .

Answer (score 0):

why not you your route use this like?

```
// Home
Route::get('/', function() {
    return View::make('home');
}));
```

i think problem is coming from **as** that you used in your route array.

Comment: No that's because I'm making use of laravel's named routes capabilities (http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#named-routes). I removed it with no effect.